# How can I sort a Map through the keyset?

Tags: java, java-stream

I wanted to sort a Map through its keyset elements in a growing way.
The join type is innerJoin.
I have this code:

```
Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>) Tuple2::get0).thenComparing(Tuple2::get1);

Map<Tuple2<String, Integer>, LongSummaryStatistics> grouped = join.stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(t -> Tuples.of(t.get1().getCNation(), t.get4().getDYear()), () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), summarizingLong(t->t.get0().getLoRevenue()-t.get0().getLoSupplycost())));

grouped.forEach((k, v) -> {
     System.out.format("%-32s, %,d%n", k, v.getSum());
});
```

That returns this result:

```
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1992}    , 9.671.947.837
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1993}    , 10.047.205.160
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1994}    , 10.141.821.441
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1992}       , 9.241.877.689
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1993}       , 9.057.962.411
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1994}       , 9.303.902.867
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1992}       , 9.746.312.266
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1993}       , 9.754.277.048
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1994}       , 10.069.331.565
...
```

And I wanted to get this result:

```
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1992}    , 9.671.947.837
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1992}       , 9.241.877.689
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1992}       , 9.746.312.266
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1993}    , 10.047.205.160
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1993}       , 9.057.962.411
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1993}       , 9.754.277.048
Tuple2Impl {ARGENTINA, 1994}    , 10.141.821.441
Tuple2Impl {BRAZIL, 1994}       , 9.303.902.867
Tuple2Impl {CANADA, 1994}       , 10.069.331.565
...
```

Comment: You would need to tell to your Comparator that you are passing to the TreeMap that in case the values are equal, he needs to sort by the key(String)

Comment: what's `Tuple2` and what is the type of  `join`?

Comment: It would be nice to implement `Comparable<Tuple2>` in `Tuple2` and compare via the value you want.

Comment: Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>) Tuple2::get0).thenComparing(Tuple2::get1); @Naman

Comment: What is `comparator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is looks like you want to order by year then nation.

```
Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer>) Tuple2::get1)
   .thenComparing(Tuple2::get0);
```

**EDIT**
Note that I use `get1` then `get0` while your code is using `get0` then `get1`.

Comment: Yes, I want this. I already have this code, but when values go to Map, they are sorted differently.

Comment: No, this solution is correct. There's a difference between your comparator and this one. You have the comparing tuple fields incorrectly ordered as: `get0` **then** `get1`; while as this solution correctly points out it should be comparing `get1` **then** `get0`.

Comment: I had switched to that and it did not work the same. It should look like this:
`Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer>) Tuple2::get1).thenComparing(Tuple2::get0);`
Thank you

Comment: You can simplify it to `Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Tuple2<String, Integer>::get1).thenComparing(Tuple2::get0);`